# Android: Resources Not Found Exception

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I'm a complete newbie to Android development, and am three weeks into a class. The program compiles and runs just fine, until I try to change any of the EditTexts, or slide the seekBar.

Assignment: Create a mortgage calculator app that allows the user to enter a purchase price, down payment amount and an interest rate. Based on these values, the app should calculate the loan amount and display the monthly payment for 10, 20, and 30 year loans. Allow the user to select a custom loan duration (in years) by using a SeekBar and display the monthly payment for that custom loan duration.

I only have the numbers being divided into years for a start, and have not implemented the interest. At the moment it's just something that gets entered and stored. But that is not the issue. This error message is what appears when I attempt to change the first edit text at all.

```
02-10 00:12:14.801    1275-1275/com.example.dakota.de_mortgage E/InputEventSender﹕ Exception dispatching finished signal.
02-10 00:12:14.802    1275-1275/com.example.dakota.de_mortgage E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-10 00:12:14.986    1275-1275/com.example.dakota.de_mortgage E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x12
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4122)
        at com.example.dakota.de_mortgage.MainActivity.updateCustom(MainActivity.java:99)
        at com.example.dakota.de_mortgage.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:18)
        at com.example.dakota.de_mortgage.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:154)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7663)
        at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7723)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9440)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:964)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:515)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:454)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
        at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5787)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5600)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8338)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2306)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1682)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2699)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2221)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3918)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3611)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3772)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2185)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
        at andro
02-10 00:12:15.161    1275-1275/com.example.dakota.de_mortgage     E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dakota.de_mortgage, PID: 1275
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x12
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4122)
        at com.example.dakota.de_mortgage.MainActivity.updateCustom(MainActivity.java:99)
        at com.example.dakota.de_mortgage.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:18)
        at com.example.dakota.de_mortgage.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:154)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7663)
        at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7723)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9440)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:964)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:515)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:454)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:33)
        at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5787)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5600)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:8338)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1600)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2306)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1682)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2699)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2221)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3918)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3880)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3611)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3772)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2208)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1849)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1840)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2185)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Me
```

Here is the code.

```
package com.example.dakota.de_mortgage;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.Editable;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String CUSTOM_YEAR = "CUSTOM_YEAR";
private static final String YEAR_PAY1 = "YEAR_PAY1";
private static final String YEAR_PAY2 = "YEAR_PAY2";
private static final String YEAR_PAY3 = "YEAR_PAY3";

private int currentCustomYear;
private double purchaseGiven;
private double downGiven;
private double interestGiven;
private double moneyRemain;

private TextView customTextView;
private TextView customYearView;
private EditText tenYearResult;
private EditText twntyYearResult;
private EditText thrtyYearResult;
private EditText customYearResult;
private EditText purchaseDown;
private EditText downText;
private EditText interestText;
private SeekBar customSeekBar;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    moneyRemain = 0;

    customTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customTextView);
    customYearView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customYearView);
    tenYearResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tenYearResult);
    twntyYearResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.twntyYearResult);
    thrtyYearResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thrtyYearResult);
    customYearResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customYearResult);
    purchaseDown = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.purchaseDown);
    downText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.downText);
    interestText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.interestText);

    purchaseDown.addTextChangedListener(purchaseWatcher);
    downText.addTextChangedListener(downWatcher);
    interestText.addTextChangedListener(interestWatcher);

    if ( savedInstanceState == null )
    {
        purchaseGiven = 1.0;
        downGiven = 1.0;
        interestGiven = 1.0;
        currentCustomYear = 18;
    }
    else
    {
        purchaseGiven = savedInstanceState.getDouble(YEAR_PAY1);
        downGiven = savedInstanceState.getDouble(YEAR_PAY2);
        interestGiven = savedInstanceState.getDouble(YEAR_PAY3);

        currentCustomYear =
                savedInstanceState.getInt(CUSTOM_YEAR);
    }

    SeekBar customSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.customSeekBar);
    customSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListener);
}

private void updateStandard()
{
    moneyRemain = purchaseGiven - downGiven;
    tenYearResult.setText(String.format("%.02f", moneyRemain / 10));
    twntyYearResult.setText(String.format("%.02f", moneyRemain / 20));
    thrtyYearResult.setText(String.format("%.03f", moneyRemain / 30));
}


private void updateCustom()
{
    moneyRemain = purchaseGiven - downGiven;
    customYearView.setText(currentCustomYear);

    customYearResult.setText(String.format("%.02f", moneyRemain / currentCustomYear));
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putInt(CUSTOM_YEAR, currentCustomYear);
    outState.putDouble(YEAR_PAY1, purchaseGiven);
    outState.putDouble(YEAR_PAY2, downGiven);
    outState.putDouble(YEAR_PAY3, interestGiven);
}

private OnSeekBarChangeListener customSeekBarListener =  new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
    {
        currentCustomYear = seekBar.getProgress();
        updateCustom();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
    {
    }
};

private TextWatcher purchaseWatcher = new TextWatcher()
{

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                              int before, int count)
    {

        try
        {
            purchaseGiven = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            purchaseGiven = 1.0;
        }


        updateStandard();
        updateCustom();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after)
    {
    }
};

private TextWatcher downWatcher = new TextWatcher()
{

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence t, int start,
                              int before, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            downGiven = Double.parseDouble(t.toString());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            downGiven = 1.0;
        }

        updateStandard();
        updateCustom();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable t)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence t, int start, int count,
                                  int after)
    {
    }
};

private TextWatcher interestWatcher = new TextWatcher()
{

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                              int before, int count)
    {

        try
        {
            interestGiven = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            interestGiven = 1.0;
        }


        updateStandard();
        updateCustom();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after)
    {
    }
};
}
```

And here is the xml if that matters.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFF" android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
android:stretchColumns="1,2,3" android:padding="5dp">

<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow0">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/purchase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Purchase" android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="right" android:paddingRight="5dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/purchaseDown"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_span="3"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:layout_weight="1">
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

//row 9
<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow9">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Down" android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="right" android:paddingRight="5dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/downText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_span="3"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:layout_weight="1">
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow3">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/interest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Interest" android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="right" android:paddingRight="5dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/interestText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_span="3"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:layout_weight="1">
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow2">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tenYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10 Years" android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="right" android:paddingRight="5dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tenYearResult"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="0.0"
        android:gravity="center" android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="14sp"
        android:cursorVisible="false" android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/twntyYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20 Years" android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="right" android:paddingRight="5dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/twntyYearResult"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="0.0"
        android:gravity="center" android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="14sp"
        android:cursorVisible="false" android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow5">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/thrtyYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30 Years" android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="right" android:paddingRight="5dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thrtyYearResult"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="0.0"
        android:gravity="center" android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="14sp"
        android:cursorVisible="false" android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow4">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/customTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Custom"
        android:textColor="#000" android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:focusable="false"></TextView>
    <SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/customSeekBar" android:layout_span="2"
        android:progress="18" android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp" android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"></SeekBar>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/customYearView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="18"
        android:textColor="#000" android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tableRow6">
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/customYearResult"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="0.0"
        android:gravity="center" android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="14sp"
        android:cursorVisible="false" android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </EditText>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I've spent hours trying to fix it myself and looking for a solution. I don't know if I have been looking at the wrong places or what, but I'm at the end of my rope.

Thank you for any help you may be able to give. If there's more info required, please just ask.

Edit: Added full error message.

Comment: Uh oh- Did you just copy the xml file without any modification? If so, you will have to remove `//row 9` on the line #20.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to: Please include the entire error messages.  Given that the error messages list line numbers please make sure that the code you have provided exactly matches the code from which you obtained the error messages. It currently does not match the line numbers in the error text.

Comment: I think @Vivek's answer will resolve your problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see one mistake in your code..

please use this line

```
customYearView.setText(""+currentCustomYear);
```

instead of this

```
customYearView.setText(currentCustomYear);
```

As TextView accepts String value.

Answer (score 0):

After compiling your code i have found out the error in line

**customYearView.setText(currentCustomYear);**

where currentCustomYear is integer value.

Update your method to below

```
private void updateCustom() {

        moneyRemain = purchaseGiven - downGiven;
        
        customYearView.setText(""+ currentCustomYear);

        customYearResult.setText(String.format("%.02f", moneyRemain
                / currentCustomYear));
    }
```

Reason for your crash is you were setting an integer value on TextView but textview only accepts Character Sequence

From the Android Docs

```
public final void setText (CharSequence text)
```

More information is available [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`customYearView.setText(String.valueOf(currentCustomYear));`

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".